# Почему right работает некорректно?

Tags: css

L-RES выполняется один раз, R-RES выполняется бесконечно как и должно быть.
L и R по своему коду практически идентичны
Второй день уже голову ломаю, ну где ошибка?

```js
$button_left = document.querySelector('#button_left')
$button_right = document.querySelector('#button_right')
$button_reset = document.querySelector('#button_reset')
$parent = document.querySelector('#parent')


$button_left.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $parent.style.right = 0 
    $parent.style.right = 200 + 'px'
})

$button_right.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $parent.style.left = 0
    $parent.style.left = 200 + 'px'
})

$button_reset.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $parent.style.left = 0
    $parent.style.right = 0 
})
```

```css
*{margin: 0;}

#button_left{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 500px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
#button_right{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 600px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
#button_reset{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 700px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
#parent{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 600px;
    height: 210px;
    position: relative;
}
#box_1{
    background-color: brown;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
#box_2{
    background-color: gold;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
}
#box_3{
    background-color: chartreuse;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
}
```

```html
        <div id="parent">
            <div id="box_1"></div>
            <div id="box_2"></div>
            <div id="box_3"></div>
        **</div>
        <button id="button_left">L</button>
        <button id="button_right">R</button>
        <button id="button_reset">RES</button>
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас возникает ситуация когда к элементу с фикс. шириной применяется и `left` и `right`. В таком случае применяется только одно из свойтсв. Решение: всякий раз при установке горизонтального позиционирования убирать противоположное свойство:

```js
$button_left = document.querySelector('#button_left')
$button_right = document.querySelector('#button_right')
$button_reset = document.querySelector('#button_reset')
$parent = document.querySelector('#parent')


$button_left.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $parent.style.left = '';
    $parent.style.right = 200 + 'px'
})

$button_right.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $parent.style.right = '';
    $parent.style.left = 200 + 'px'
})

$button_reset.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $parent.style.left = '';
    $parent.style.right = '';
})
```

```css
*{margin: 0;}

#button_left{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 500px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
#button_right{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 600px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
#button_reset{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 700px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
#parent{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 600px;
    height: 210px;
    position: relative;
}
#box_1{
    background-color: brown;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
#box_2{
    background-color: gold;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
}
#box_3{
    background-color: chartreuse;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
            <div id="box_1"></div>
            <div id="box_2"></div>
            <div id="box_3"></div>
        **</div>
        <button id="button_left">L</button>
        <button id="button_right">R</button>
        <button id="button_reset">RES</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно работает!!!

1. Если честно не совсем понял чем отличается
    $parent.style.left = ''; от $parent.style.left = 0; но с нулем не работает

2. а что можно изменить в css, не изменяя изначальный js?

Comment: 1) 0 - это такое же цифровое значение для `left` и `right`. Соответственно - поведение будет таким же. Если не хочется сбрасывать эти свойства пустой строкой, можно устанавливать для них значение `auto`; 2) Наверное ничего. Нужные вам стили по идее  пишутся через `js` непосредственно в атрибут `style` элемента

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: @zhurof, `В таком случае применяется только одно из свойтсв` Разве? По моему если установить left: 0 и right: 0, элемент растянется на всю ширину.

Comment: хотя действительно если удалить:
$button_right.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $parent.style.right = '';
    $parent.style.left = 200 + 'px'
})

и оставить только L-RES то точно так же не работает
а если оставить только R-RES то все работает
как это объяснить?

Comment: @OliverPatterson , только если у позиционируемого элемента ширина `auto`. И то не во всех браузерах

Comment: @KoTTBarsik , в текущем ответе прямо сейчас использовал несколько раз только кнопки `L` и `RES`. Всё работает как и в полном варианте

Comment: Все работает если как Вы писали $parent.style.left = '';

А если оставить только:

Не работает
$parent.style.left = 0;
$parent.style.right = 200 + 'px'

либо

Работает
$parent.style.right = 0
$parent.style.left = 200 + 'px'

Почему одно работает а другое нет?

Comment: При условии что $parent.style.left = 0;   button_left + button_reset не работают
   button_right + button_reset работают